# What is going on during git's "remote processing"

Tags: git, push, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Every time I push to a git remote there is a line that says "remote: processing..."
This usually goes really fast when I push to github or Bitbucket but when I push to an Amazon Beanstalk deployment it takes between 10 seconds and 2 minutes".

What exactly is the remote "processing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you refer to `git aws.push` that takes so long. The reason is that `git push` submits your changed files (commits) to the remote git repository while `git aws.push` issues AWS API commands to transfer your files to Elastic Beanstalk.
To see that, you can check out the script that's executed during this command. run this:
`cat .git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push`

You'll see that the so called `git aws.push` command is actually a script that uses AWS API and has nothing to do with git repositories.