# It takes way too long to deploy on elasticbeanstalk. I am loosing patience

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Why does it take so long to deploy on Elastic Beanstalk even if I just change a single file? I so wish it would recognize file changes and apply them on top of the version.

Answer (score 5):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144160/what-is-going-on-during-gits-remote-processing/26841526#26841526), Elastic Beanstalk deployment isn't smart. Even though it works with git, it doesn't use deltas and uploads the entire repository every time you deploy. I found no way around that.