# Elastic Beanstalk with git

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node app that is approximately 450mb. The .git/ folder is around 200mb. I'm deploying my app with the EB cli using this tutorial

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html

My problem is that whenever I make a minor change, the file that get's uploaded is always around 200mb (no matter how minor of a change I make). Why isn't it only uploading the relevant code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144160/what-is-going-on-during-gits-remote-processing/26841526#26841526). Elastic beanstalk fetches your git content, zipps it, and uploads to S3. It doesn't work with deltas, unfortunately.

What can you do?

1. make sure your git repository is clean from unnecessary files. use `.gitignore`
2. store big static files in S3, and not in git
3. use a cloud server to deploy to EB, which has bigger bandwidth and is closer to AWS. I'm using Wercker to build my app and deploy to Eb.